# How to publish readme file automatically along with package in NuGet org through GitHub actions CI/CD pipeline

Tags: nuget, github-actions, nuget-package-restore, nugetgallery

Details about Problem

When uploading a package to nuget.org manually via the website, I can set a documentation URL that points to a readme file on github, as shown here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/blazor-server-githubactions-demo/ How do I this via a .csproject file, as I use CI / CD to publish my packages and so I don't want this to be a manual step. how publish readme file automatically along with pacakge.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try, but according to [this blog post from Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/add-a-readme-to-your-nuget-package/), I'd expect the following to work

1. Create `README.md` in your repo.
2. Ensure your `csproj` file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        ...
        <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        ...
        <None Include="docs\README.md" Pack="true" PackagePath="\"/>
        ...
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This should configure everything in your NuGet package, so that it gets picked up when being uploaded to nuget.org.

Comment: Thanks @mu88. I tried the same thing but i didn't see the readme.md file in  nuget.org.

Comment: And is it present in your NuGet package (`docs\README.md`)? If not, can you try it with the mentioned Preview version of .NET 6?

Comment: I change the version of .NET from 3.1.101 to 6.0.x. its working now readme.md file publish automatically along with package. Thanks @mu88

Comment: Cool, I'm happy I could help :) If this suffices your needs, please consider accepting it as an answer so that the question gets closed